# Test annotated with @DataJpaTest not autowiring field annotated with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot app which contains a Spring Data Jpa repository. I need to run a unit (or component?) test around this repository. I do not have a lot of experience with Spring Data Jpa.

Here's my test. It's trivially simple, and I cannot get it to pass.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepo;

    @Test
    public void notNull(){
        assertNotNull(fooRepo);
    }
}
```

Here's the other relevant source code.

```
import com.fedex.dockmaintenancetool.webservice.types.Foo;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

and

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Foo {
}
```

I am *just* trying to get a Jpa repo autowired into a test, and I can't. Clearly I'm misunderstanding some small nuance of how Spring Boot works. But even after going through some tutorials, I cannot figure out what I'm missing. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try annotating your `FooRepository` with `@Repository`

Comment: @JacobG. Oof. I made a typo when writing my simplified example code. I've fixed it now, but I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: Can you also post your main class?

Comment: @JacobG. The main class is actually in a completely separate module. It can't even be referenced from this test.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? Before 2.1 you need `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the annotation `@DataJpaTest` , it means that you are trying to test only the repository layer. The annotation is used to test JPA repositories and is used in combination with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to enable populating the application context. The `@DataJpaTest` annotation disables full auto-configuration and applies only configuration relevant to JPA tests.So as @fap siggested use it like :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepo;

    @Test
    public void notNull(){
        assertNotNull(fooRepo);
    }
}
```

When you use the annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` the SpringRunner provides support for loading a Spring ApplicationContext and having beans `@Autowired` into your test instance.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand - the @DataJpaTest annotation only instantiates enough of the app context to run the JPA tests, but doesn't instantiate the entire app context?

Comment: @AugustZellmer yes, so for autowiring beans that are not part of the jpa layer you need to have an application context.That is why we need the springRunner.

Comment: You need an application context for autowiring to work at all. The `@XyzTest` application determines which slice of your application gets loaded into the application context for this test class. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/test-auto-configuration.html to learn more about test slices.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, both of you.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation that tells JUnit to actually start a Spring application for the test.

Your test class should look like

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class FooRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepo;

    @Test
    public void notNull(){
        assertNotNull(fooRepo);
    }
}
```

The JUnit version used in the question is still JUnit 4.
Spring Boot 2.2.0 switches to JUnit5.

With JUnit5 you'll have to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` instead of `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Since `@JpaTest` is already annotated with `@ExtendsWith` you don't have to actually include it though, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65359510/4266296.

Comment: I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test` : were you not getting this error when trying out only those 2 annotations you suggested ?

Comment: @payne The test should automatically pick up your class that you've annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and use it to initialize the application context for the test. You can try to use `@ContextConfiguration(classes = { YourSpringBootApplicationClass.class })` to point to it manually.
But it would be better to post a new question with your specific context (Spring version, code excerpts etc.) instead of asking in the comments for a different question.