# @Autowired should not work without @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) but does

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, dependency-injection, repository

Here is a unit testing class for a java spring data repository layer.
I have a spring data repository layer in which the annotation @Autowired is used to inject TestEntityManager type object (belongs to spring data package).
The autowiring works whitout adding @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation !
So what is the problem ? Well, I think that injection should not be possible whitout adding @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) annotation to the class : it should not work without it theorically.
How is it possible ? Does someone have any answer ?

[>>>> view complete spring boot app code on github available here](https://github.com/userInterview/LoizSpringRestPersistenceTests/blob/main/src/test/java/org/loiz/demo/LoizPersistenceTest.java)

- Someone else have had **the opposite problem** in stackoverflow :

[Someone else have had the opposite problem : see link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634359/test-annotated-with-datajpatest-not-autowiring-field-annotated-with-autowired)

Here is my strange bloc of code that amazingly that works :

package org.loiz.demo;

```
import org.assertj.core.api.BDDAssertions;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test ;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order ;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import demo.LoizBootSpringDemoApplication;
import demo.crepository.UserRepositoryInterface;
import demo.dmodel.User;
import demo.helper.helperUtils;

//Test de la couche de persistence
//@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { LoizBootSpringDemoApplication.class})
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class LoizPersistenceTest 
{
    
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepositoryInterface repository; 

    private static Long idStub ;
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    @Rollback(false)
    @DisplayName("Test de sauvegarde d\'un user \"prenom21 Nom21\"")    
    public void saveShouldMapCorrectly() throws Exception {
        
        User userStub = new User("prenom21", "Nom21");                       
        
        User UserSaved = this.testEntityManager.persistFlushFind(userStub);
        
        BDDAssertions.then(UserSaved.getId()).isNotNull();                    
        idStub = UserSaved.getId() ;
        
        User UserRead = this.testEntityManager.find(User.class, idStub) ;       
        
        BDDAssertions.then(UserSaved.getFirstName()).isNotBlank();
        BDDAssertions.then(UserSaved.getFirstName()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("prenom21");
        

        BDDAssertions.then(UserSaved.getLastName()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("Nom21");
        BDDAssertions.then(UserSaved.getLastName()).isNotBlank();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2) 
    @DisplayName("Test d'existence du user \"prenom21 Nom21\"") 
    public void readShouldMapCorrectly() throws Exception {
        User userStub = new User(idStub, "prenom21", "Nom21");          
        User userFetched  = this.testEntityManager.find(User.class, idStub) ;
        
        String sUserStub = userStub.toString() ;        
        String sUserFetched = userFetched.toString() ;      
        
        
        boolean bolSameObject = userStub.equals(userFetched) ;
        
        boolean bolAttrEgalEgal = sUserStub == sUserFetched ;       
        
        boolean bolStringEqual = sUserStub.equals(sUserFetched) ;           
        
        boolean bBeanUtil = helperUtils.haveSamePropertyValues (User.class,userStub,userFetched) ;
        
                
        Assert.assertTrue(bBeanUtil);
        
    }

}
```

Maybe it is normal, but what do i have to know ?
I would appreciate some answer please :)

[>>>> view complete spring boot app code on github available here](https://github.com/userInterview/LoizSpringRestPersistenceTests/blob/main/src/test/java/org/loiz/demo/LoizPersistenceTest.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is used for junit 4 test.
But in our case, it is Junit 5 that is used. That is what we can see reading at the  `pom.xml` file (using of `junit.jupiter` artifact proves that).
So `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` has no effects to manage spring container.
it should be replaced by `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

**HOWEVER :**

`@DataJpaTest` already "contains" `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` !!!
So we don't need to add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` when `@DataJpaTest` is used.
`@DataJpaTest` will allow to test spring data repository layer but will also guarantee spring dependency injection.
That is to say, and roughly speeking, you can use `@Autowired` annotation for a class which is annotated `@DataJpaTest` (a spring data repository layer).

Answer (score 1):

From imports `junit.jupiter` i can see you are using [junit-5](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests), were `@RunWith` belongs to [junit-4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html), and for reference `@ExtendWith` is not mandataroy for junit-5 test and if you want to use a specific runner you still require the `@ExtendsWith` but as [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) itself is annotated with `@ExtendsWith` you don't need to do this explicitly

> In JUnit 5, the `@RunWith` annotation has been replaced by the more powerful `@ExtendWith` annotation.

> To use this class, simply annotate a JUnit 4 based test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` or `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot "DeadPool"  

Comment: Well if you want to use a specific runner you still require the `@ExtendsWith` **but** as `@DataJpaTest` itself is annotated with `@ExtendsWith` you don't need to do this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum updated the answer and thanks again for always helping me to learn new things

Comment: To M. Deinum > You are right.
I write myself an answer to my own question so that some anonym web viewer be gving some clear answer.